# SUM and GROUP BY not working

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

I encounter a worry in my request, it does not run correctly.
Can you help me please ?

```
$ref_je = $pdo->query("SELECT SUM(Winner) AS Winn, SUM(Participation) AS Part, Reponse FROM tb_jeu_jeudi_reponses WHERE Pseudo='".$Pseudo."' GROUP BY Reponse");
while($data_je = $ref_je->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$Jeu_W = number_format($data_je["Winn"], 0, ',', ' ');
$Jeu_P = number_format($data_je["Part"], 0, ',', ' ');
}
```

The GROUP BY does not actually work.
Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Can you quantify `does not actually work`?  Your query looks logically correct to me.  Do you get an error, or do you just get unexpected output?

Comment: Also, the description of the table would help to help.

Comment: No I have no mistake but the sum is false. Instead of having a total of "1", I have "2", I put an example of a table below